# How to configure spring mvc project on AWS instances for hazelcast?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, hazelcast

My two spring mvc hazelcast application deployed on two different instances on AWS. currently i am using following hazelcast.xml for config. let me know the configuration for AWS.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
                    <hz:aws enabled="true">

                        <region>eu-central-1</region>

                        <tag-key>aws:cloudformation:stack-name</tag-key>

                        <tag-value>EC2ContainerService-test-cluster</tag-value>

                    </hz:aws>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>

</beans>
```

i have gone throug aws cobnfiguration xml for the same.

```
<region>eu-central-1</region>

<tag-key>aws:cloudformation:stack-name</tag-key>

<tag-value>EC2ContainerService-test-cluster</tag-value>
```

but it throws error. so please correct the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct configuration in test hazelcast configs at the GitHub repo, for example, [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-spring/src/test/resources/com/hazelcast/spring/fullConfig-applicationContext-hazelcast.xml).

In your case, you need to change the configuration to the following.

```
<hz:aws enabled="true"
        region="eu-central-1"
        tag-key=aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
        tag-value="EC2ContainerService-test-cluster"/>
```